# Jquery keypress 37 issue, '%' and [ left arrow ] not work in IE 10

Tags: javascript, jquery, keypress

Good morning,

I facing a issue on the IE 10 where my keypress still can enter '%' but the FF and Chrome no such issue.
I found out that the key 37 is the [ left arrow ] which match with '%' in ASCII.
My sample code as below:

```
$('#refId').bind("keypress", function(event) {
            // allow  letters, numbers and keypad numbers ONLY
            var key = event.charCode;
            if((key >= 48 && key <= 57) ||
                (key >= 65 && key <= 90) ||
                (key >= 97 && key <= 122)){
                return true;
            }

            //allow backspace, tab, left arrows, right arrow, delete
            key = event.keyCode;
            if(key == 8 || 
                    key == 9 ||
                    key == 37 ||
                    key == 39 ||
                    key == 46){
                return true;
            }

            return false; 
    });
```

Can give me some idea how to fix this?

Thanks.
-fsloke

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38607309/only-want-leftarrow-right-arrow-and-numbers/38607826

Answer (score 0):

Use `var key = event.which;` instead and join the if-statements.

> The event.which property normalizes event.keyCode and event.charCode.
>   It is recommended to watch event.which for keyboard key input.
>
> *- https://api.jquery.com/event.which/*

```
$('#refId').on("keydown", function(event) {
    // allow letters, numbers and keypad numbers ONLY
    var key = event.which;
    if((key >= 48 && key <= 57) ||
        (key >= 65 && key <= 90) ||
        (key >= 97 && key <= 122) ||
        key == 8 || 
        key == 9 ||
        key == 37 ||
        key == 39 ||
        key == 46) {
        return true;
    }

    return false; 
});
```

Comment: I did using which but still no fix this issue. Thanks.