# only want leftArrow right arrow and numbers

Tags: javascript, jquery

If I press left arrow `event.KeyCode` gives me 37.

If I press % symbol `event.which` gives me 37.

What to do in that situation, I only want to allow left arrow.

```
$('.cla').keypress(function(event) {
    var key = event.Which || event.keyCode
    if ((key >= 48 && key <= 57) || (key == 37)) {
        return true;
    } else return false;
});
```

Comment: Why are you rolling back? I've improved your post!

Comment: do that thing which leads to answer my question i am not sying my code is not working please be on track

Comment: That's exactly what I do. I've edited your question so as it is easier to read.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to press % you need to also press the shift key right ?

So if the shift key is pressed it should match the % symbol, the left arrow otherwise.
You can check if the shift key is pressed with **event.shiftKey**

Answer (score 1):

`keyPress` does not include arrow keys - fiddle confirmation: https://jsfiddle.net/12a25f46/

`keyPress` `event.which` returns the ASCII character code that the key generates (eg Shift+A=65) - which makes no sense for arrow keys as they don't generate a character.  So arrow keys are not included in keyPress.

`keyUp` / `keyDown` `event.which` shows the keyCode of the key pressed and will include arrows and whether shift(etc) was pressed.

---

So checking just `keyPress` will allow you to check for numbers and % and also allow the cursor to be moved via the arrow keys.

*Separately* checking for `keyUp` (or `keyDown`) will allow you to check any key, but it will not use the same numbers (eg % is 53+shift, not 37)

So there's no conflict.

---

Update: according to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31331548/jquery-keypress-37-issue-and-left-arrow-not-work-in-ie-10) (which is somewhat similar...) this might be an issue in *IE10*.   Fiddle above tested in chrome and IE11, not IE10.

Another [valid answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19347349/2181514) the indicates `keypress` may be working incorrectly in some browsers.